# Difference between Rotate[] and Translate[]

Tags: graphics, rotation

I don't understand why `Rotate[]` and `Translate[]` behave differently. For example,
ga and gb below look as I expected:

```
ga = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]];
Print[ga];
gb = Rotate[ga, \[Pi]/4, {0, 0}];
Print[gb];
gc = Translate[gb, {1, 1}];
Print[gc];
```

But gc results in this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are calling Graphics too early. You want to `Rotate` and `Translate` the `Line`, not the `Graphics`.

```
ga = Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}];
Graphics[ga]
gb = Rotate[ga, \[Pi]/4, {0, 0}];
Graphics[gb]
gc = Translate[gb, {1, 1}];
Graphics[gc]
```

Will do what you want.

```
Graphics[{Red, ga, Blue, gb, Green, gc}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! ${}{}$

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke just to add to this: for some reason WRI decided that `Rotate` should _also_ be able to rotate arbitrary stuff displayed on the screen outside of a `Graphics` call, which is why your `gb` _seemed_ to work.